# React Navigation: How to go back to root Tab Navigator with specific tab from child stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using **react-navigation v2** in React Native and get stuck whenever want to go back to a **specific** tab in the root navigator.

I've the following route stack:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    CreateInvoice: CreateInvoiceScreen,
    InvoiceSummary: InvoiceSummaryScreen,
    PinEntry: PinEntryScreen
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);

const CustomersStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Customers: CustomersScreen,
    Details: CustomerDetailsScreen
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Transactions: TransactionsTab,
    Customers: CustomersStack,
    Settings: SettingsTab
  }
);

const Routers = createStackNavigator({
  splash: {
    screen: SplashScreen,
    navigationOptions: {...navigationOptions}
  },
  login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {...navigationOptions}
  },
  home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {...navigationOptions}
  }
});
```

I'm now in **PinEntry** screen and I want to go back to **Transactions** tab in TabNavigator. I can go back to *Home* tab using the following script:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate('Home')]
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But my goal is to go back to specific tab position, in this case is **'Transactions'** tab.

I've googled it so many times but with no solution, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('Transactions')  without reset stack works correctly for me...

Comment: @ali-sn Yes, it works, but I need to reset my stack to that screen. How to do it with reset stack?

Comment: I will tell you if i found a solution...! :-D

Comment: @ali-sn I found the solution, using 2 dispatches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })]
});
const goToTransaction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Transactions'
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
this.props.navigation.dispatch(goToTransaction);
```